# Are units of force on prismatic joints Newtons?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

As opposed to newton-meters as shown in the 2.2.3 UI.

In my case I'm using ROS Indigo and I have an EffortJointInterface with a mechanicalReduction of 1.  when I echo the state for the position controller it has a command field I believe to be newton-meters when the joint is rotary, but is it newtons for prismatic?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/7434/are-units-of-force-on-prismatic-joints-newtons?/) by [Lucas Walter](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/531/lucas-walter/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 115 on 2014-11-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

As long as all other units you use are SI-metric consistent, then yes, it's Newtons :)

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2014-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lucas Walter](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/531/lucas-walter/) on 2014-11-18**:
Thanks!  I also just did some physics experiments with primatics lifting loads against gravity and confirmed this.